# System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule does not implement IHttpHandlerFactory or IHttpHandler.?

Tags: asp.net

I am running nopCommerce and I am getting the following error when I try to upload a picture with one of their widgets :

Error
The log entry message.Short message:

```
System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule does not implement IHttpHandlerFactory or IHttpHandler.
The details for the log entry.Full message: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule does not implement IHttpHandlerFactory or IHttpHandler. at System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache.GetHandlerType(String type) at System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache..ctor(String type) at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(String type) at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
IP address of the machine that caused the exception.IP address: 178.162.198.164
Name of the customer who caused the exception.Customer: b@search_engine_record.com
Originating page of exception.Page URL: http://northseaworkwear.com/robots.txt
The referrer URL.Referrer URL:  
Date/Time the log entry was created.Created on: 1/5/2015 4:06:10 PM
```

What could be the problem ? Low disk space on the server ?